# Prove unequal with numbers in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have problems to prove the following inequality:

Let $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $b_{1}$, $b_{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ then:

$$\left( \frac{b_{1}+b_{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}}\right)^{a_{1}+a_{2}}>\left( \frac{b_{1}}{a_{1}}\right)^{a_{1}}\left( \frac{b_{2}}{a_{2}}\right)^{a_{2}}$$

where: $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $b_{1}$, $b_{2}$ are all different.

I was unable to make the show, and I begin to doubt that is true why come to ask if it is valid or not, should be true if I can help with testing, I was the grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x = b(1)/a(1) > 0 and y = b(2)/a(2) > 0. Then we need to prove:

((x*a(1) + y*a(2))/(a(1) + a(2)))^(a(1) + a(2)) > x^(a(1))*y^(a(2)  <====>

(a(1) + a(2))*ln(x*a(1)/(a(1) + a(2)) + y*a(2)/(a(1) + a(2))) > (a(1)/(a(1) + a(2)))*lnx +

- (a(2)/(a(1) + a(2)))*lny.

Let m = a(1)/(a(1) + a(2)) > 0, and n = a(2)/(a(1) + a(2)) > 0 then m + n = 1. So we prove:

ln(mx + ny) > mlnx + nlny with m, n > 0 and m + n = 1. Observe that f(t) = lnt is concave

if t > 0 because f''(t) = -1/t^2 < 0. So Jensen's inequality applies to get the answer.